# Get the encrypted payload from an unencrypted wrapper PDF document

Tags: java, beginner, comparative-review, cyclomatic-complexity

This is code, written by our dev team, and SonarQube tells me that the *Cognitive Complexity* is too high: *21*, and the current (default, out of the box) metric limit is *15*. I've had a go at reducing the complexity and would love some feedback.

For those interested, the full source code is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/kernel/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfDocument.java#L1522).

The code does the following:

- Is the current PDF document instance encrypted -> bail out
- Is the current PDF unencrypted, get the embedded file inside the wrapper document, if any
- Return the encrypted payload that is inside the wrapper document

For more details, please refer to the PDF specification ISO 32000-1:2008.

---

**Original code**

```
/**
 * Gets the encrypted payload of this document,
 * or returns {@code null} if this document isn't an unencrypted wrapper document.
 *
 * @return encrypted payload of this document.
 */
public PdfEncryptedPayloadDocument getEncryptedPayloadDocument2() {
    if (getReader() != null && getReader().isEncrypted()) {
        return null;
    }
    PdfCollection collection = getCatalog().getCollection();
    if (collection != null && collection.isViewHidden()) {
        PdfString documentName = collection.getInitialDocument();
        PdfNameTree embeddedFiles = getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.EmbeddedFiles);
        String documentNameUnicode = documentName.toUnicodeString();
        PdfObject fileSpecObject = embeddedFiles.getNames().get(documentNameUnicode);
        if (fileSpecObject != null && fileSpecObject.isDictionary()) {
            try {
                PdfFileSpec fileSpec = PdfEncryptedPayloadFileSpecFactory.wrap((PdfDictionary) fileSpecObject);
                if (fileSpec != null) {
                    PdfDictionary embeddedDictionary = ((PdfDictionary) fileSpec.getPdfObject()).getAsDictionary(PdfName.EF);
                    PdfStream stream = embeddedDictionary.getAsStream(PdfName.UF);
                    if (stream == null) {
                        stream = embeddedDictionary.getAsStream(PdfName.F);
                    }
                    if (stream != null) {
                        return new PdfEncryptedPayloadDocument(stream, fileSpec, documentNameUnicode);
                    }
                }
            } catch (PdfException e) {
                LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Goals of the refactoring:

- lower complexity
- better readability
- better testability
- better maintainability

---

**Refactored code**

```
/**
 * Gets the encrypted payload of this document,
 * or returns {@code null} if this document isn't an unencrypted wrapper document.
 *
 * @return encrypted payload of this document.
 */
public PdfEncryptedPayloadDocument getEncryptedPayloadDocument2() {
    if (readerIsEncrypted(getReader())) {
        return null;
    }
    PdfCollection collection = getCatalog().getCollection();
    if (collectionIsNotViewHidden(collection)) {
        return null;
    }
    PdfString documentName = collection.getInitialDocument();
    PdfNameTree embeddedFiles = getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.EmbeddedFiles);
    String documentNameUnicode = documentName.toUnicodeString();
    PdfObject fileSpecObject = embeddedFiles.getNames().get(documentNameUnicode);
    if (fileSpecObjectIsNoDictionary(fileSpecObject)) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        PdfFileSpec fileSpec = PdfEncryptedPayloadFileSpecFactory.wrap((PdfDictionary) fileSpecObject);
        if (fileSpec != null) {
            PdfDictionary embeddedDictionary = ((PdfDictionary) fileSpec.getPdfObject()).getAsDictionary(PdfName.EF);
            PdfStream stream = getPdfStreamUf(embeddedDictionary);
            if (stream != null) {
                return new PdfEncryptedPayloadDocument(stream, fileSpec, documentNameUnicode);
            }
        }
    } catch (PdfException e) {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

private boolean readerIsEncrypted(PdfReader reader) {
    return reader != null && reader.isEncrypted();
}

private boolean collectionIsNotViewHidden(PdfCollection collection) {
    return collection == null || !collection.isViewHidden();
}

private boolean fileSpecObjectIsNoDictionary(PdfObject fileSpecObject) {
    return fileSpecObject == null || !fileSpecObject.isDictionary();
}

private PdfStream getPdfStreamUf(PdfDictionary dictionary) {
    PdfStream stream = dictionary.getAsStream(PdfName.UF);
    if (stream == null) {
        stream = dictionary.getAsStream(PdfName.F);
    }
    return stream;
}
```

**`git diff`**

```
@ -1557,36 +1513,55 @@ public class PdfDocument implements IEventDispatcher, Closeable, Serializable {
      * @return encrypted payload of this document.
      */
     public PdfEncryptedPayloadDocument getEncryptedPayloadDocument2() {
-        if (getReader() != null && getReader().isEncrypted()) {
+        if (readerIsEncrypted(getReader())) {
             return null;
         }
         PdfCollection collection = getCatalog().getCollection();
-        if (collection != null && collection.isViewHidden()) {
-            PdfString documentName = collection.getInitialDocument();
-            PdfNameTree embeddedFiles = getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.EmbeddedFiles);
-            String documentNameUnicode = documentName.toUnicodeString();
-            PdfObject fileSpecObject = embeddedFiles.getNames().get(documentNameUnicode);
-            if (fileSpecObject != null && fileSpecObject.isDictionary()) {
-                try {
-                    PdfFileSpec fileSpec = PdfEncryptedPayloadFileSpecFactory.wrap((PdfDictionary) fileSpecObject);
-                    if (fileSpec != null) {
-                        PdfDictionary embeddedDictionary = ((PdfDictionary) fileSpec.getPdfObject()).getAsDictionary(PdfName.EF);
-                        PdfStream stream = embeddedDictionary.getAsStream(PdfName.UF);
-                        if (stream == null) {
-                            stream = embeddedDictionary.getAsStream(PdfName.F);
-                        }
-                        if (stream != null) {
-                            return new PdfEncryptedPayloadDocument(stream, fileSpec, documentNameUnicode);
-                        }
-                    }
-                } catch (PdfException e) {
-                    LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).error(e.getMessage());
+        if (collectionIsNotViewHidden(collection)) {
+            return null;
+        }
+        PdfString documentName = collection.getInitialDocument();
+        PdfNameTree embeddedFiles = getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.EmbeddedFiles);
+        String documentNameUnicode = documentName.toUnicodeString();
+        PdfObject fileSpecObject = embeddedFiles.getNames().get(documentNameUnicode);
+        if (fileSpecObjectIsNoDictionary(fileSpecObject)) {
+            return null;
+        }
+        try {
+            PdfFileSpec fileSpec = PdfEncryptedPayloadFileSpecFactory.wrap((PdfDictionary) fileSpecObject);
+            if (fileSpec != null) {
+                PdfDictionary embeddedDictionary = ((PdfDictionary) fileSpec.getPdfObject()).getAsDictionary(PdfName.EF);
+                PdfStream stream = getPdfStreamUf(embeddedDictionary);
+                if (stream != null) {
+                    return new PdfEncryptedPayloadDocument(stream, fileSpec, documentNameUnicode);
                 }
             }
+        } catch (PdfException e) {
+            LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).error(e.getMessage());
         }
         return null;
     }

+    private boolean readerIsEncrypted(PdfReader reader) {
+        return reader != null && reader.isEncrypted();
+    }
+
+    private boolean collectionIsNotViewHidden(PdfCollection collection) {
+        return collection == null || !collection.isViewHidden();
+    }
+
+    private boolean fileSpecObjectIsNoDictionary(PdfObject fileSpecObject) {
+        return fileSpecObject == null || !fileSpecObject.isDictionary();
+    }
+
+    private PdfStream getPdfStreamUf(PdfDictionary dictionary) {
+        PdfStream stream = dictionary.getAsStream(PdfName.UF);
+        if (stream == null) {
+            stream = dictionary.getAsStream(PdfName.F);
+        }
+        return stream;
+    }
+
     /**
      * Sets an encrypted payload, making this document an unencrypted wrapper document.
      * The file spec shall include the AFRelationship key with a value of EncryptedPayload,
```

> Summary of changes:
>
> - invert the second `if`, to have the bottom `return null` earlier.
> - invert the third `if`, also to have a `return null` earlier.
>
>   These two changes add one exit point to the method, and are used as
>     [guard clauses](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html), something I found on Martin Fowler's website
>     [refactoring.com](https://refactoring.com/).
> - extract to a private method: getting the dictionary as a stream and checking if it is `null` and then getting it in another way.
> - extract all the compound conditions to private methods.

---

The refactored code now has a cognitive complexity of *7*, well below the alert level of *15*, which means that at least one of the stated goals was achieved.

What I, from the standpoint as a tester, see as a bonus on my refactored code, is that I can look at the extracted private methods in my IDE, see that they are only partially covered by unit tests (for example 2 out of 4 conditions), and based on that information (white box testing), design a new unit test that accesses the public API to cover the missing conditions.

I am also considering to make the private methods `static`, because they only act on the input and don't use anything from the class instance. But I'm neutral on that point, it could go either way.

The concern of the developer that reported the high Cognitive Complexity, is that splitting the method up in smaller methods, would actually *reduce readability* of the code.

**Questions**

- The original code is intended as documentation, and comes from an Open Source repository on GitHub (link provided at start of question).
- Please review the **refactoring**, that is, the diff between the old code and the new code. As far as testing can tell me, functionality *should* be 100% identical. My personal goal is to become better at refactoring legacy software.
- Please do give suggestions on how the **refactoring** can be further improved. One of the items that pops into mind, is better names for the extracted methods.

**About me**

I'm a Stack Exchange veteran (see [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766786/amedee-van-gasse)), but this is my first question on the Code Review site. I'm a tester, not a developer, and it's been over a decade since I last wrote any Java code. So please be gentle with me. :-)

Comment: Now being [discussed on Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/75307).

Comment: I have implemented all of dfhwze's and ferada's suggestions, and submitted a pull request. The PR is now pending review. I will come back (and self-answer) when the review is done.

Comment: Still under review. We had a meeting about it that lasted longer than the time spent on making the actual changes. I had to un-factor all of the extracted methods. Complexity was still <15.

Answer (score 12):

### Positive Changes

- `getReader()` is only called once, while called multiple times before.
- There are more early exits as before, which results in less nested and lesser deepened nested statements.
- Method `getPdfStreamUf` hides the fallback method away from the main method, this functionality deserves its own method.

#### Negative Changes

- I agree with the developer that methods as `readerIsEncrypted`, `collectionIsNotViewHidden` and `fileSpecObjectIsNoDictionary` reduce readability. These methods are just glorified wrappers for other methods with a null check included.
- You still keep some conditions in that could have exited early `if (fileSpec != null)` and `if (stream != null)`; you could reduce nested statements further if you'd return null inverted here also.

#### Other Observations

- `getCatalog()` is still called multiple times. Call it once and cache it in a local variable.
- Make variables that don't change after being instantiated `final`.
- All in all I would prefer readability and consistency over some complexity metric, although this metric could be an indication to refactor the code. If you split up methods, make sure each method adheres to the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (though this could be interpreted any way you want :)

Comment: Thank you! This is something I can work with.

Comment: On the topic of `getCatalog()`: the chains of `getCatalog().getCollection()`, `getCatalog().getNameTree()`: that's definitely a code smell, but not one that can be addressed within the scope of this refactoring.

Comment: I inlined the glorified wrappers with included null check. Complexity is now 10, which is still below 15. So that's good.

Comment: Because all variables in the `getEncryptedPayloadDocument2()` method are only instantiated, I think they can all be final.

Comment: Yes then you have still good metrics, and preserve readability. Once you are done refactoring (but wait some more comments or answers here) you could post a follow-up question or self answer with your refactored refactored code :)

Comment: After inverting all remaining `null` checks, I can either have the very last `return null` inside the `catch` block, or keep it at the end of the method. I think I'll move it in the `catch`.

Answer (score 3):

> PDF specification ISO 32000-1:2008.

Funny, that's a roughly 800 page document if I see that right :)  You
might want to link to relevant parts if you want a reader to read it,
otherwise that doesn't really help with the review here.

The refactored version has less nesting, yes, so that's somewhat easier
to read.  However I've the feeling that the extracted helpers are bit
too short, essentially they're wrapping the null check and then combine
that with another attribute; it's not that much shorter after all.  (Edit: Actually maybe they just need better names.  Best if there's no negation in the names, `notHidden` ... well, that's just `visible`, isn't it?)

I was also going to make the comment about caching getters.  But.  Clear code is more important and one additional line for `x = getX()` looks super pointless when `x` is used only twice (or maybe even three times).  That's all assuming that getters simple return fields and *do not* have more hidden logic.  Otherwise caching might of course be necessary for performance reasons.

In any case the denesting could go even further, after all there are two
more `if`'s of the same nature:

```
    ...
    try {
        PdfFileSpec fileSpec = PdfEncryptedPayloadFileSpecFactory.wrap((PdfDictionary) fileSpecObject);
        if (fileSpec == null) {
            return null;
        }
        PdfDictionary embeddedDictionary = ((PdfDictionary) fileSpec.getPdfObject()).getAsDictionary(PdfName.EF);
        PdfStream stream = getPdfStreamUf(embeddedDictionary);
        if (stream == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new PdfEncryptedPayloadDocument(stream, fileSpec, documentNameUnicode);
    } catch (PdfException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Btw. is the `try` around the smallest section of the code that can
throw?  Otherwise It'd help to move it closer to the section that can
actually fail, possibly allowing some more restructuring too.

Unfortunately all the `null` checks can't easily be refactored in Java
like it could be done in e.g. Scala (probably Kotlin).  That also limits
how this code can be structured as it's a very imperative sequence.

I'd otherwise try and create more meaningful helpers:  If that's at all
possible I'd consider something like `getDocumentName`:

```
private String getDocumentName() {
    return getCatalog().getCollection().getInitialDocument().toUnicodeString();
}
```

Clear meaning to what this does (assuming the Unicode bit is less
important here, otherwise the name would've to encode that).

The casts are always a bit ugly, how about:

```
private PdfNameTree getEmbeddedFiles() {
    return getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.EmbeddedFiles);
}

private PdfDictionary getFileSpecDictionary(PdfNameTree embeddedFiles) {
    PdfObject fileSpecObject = embeddedFiles.getNames().get(getDocumentName());
    if (fileSpecObject == null || !fileSpecObject.isDictionary()) {
        return nil;
    }
    return (PdfDictionary) fileSpecObject;
}

private PdfDictionary getEmbeddedDictionary (PdfFileSpec fileSpec) {
    return ((PdfDictionary) fileSpec.getPdfObject()).getAsDictionary(PdfName.EF);
}
```

and then called without having to check for anything else but null:

```
PdfDictionary fileSpecObject = getFileSpecDictionary(getEmbeddedFiles());
if (fileSpecObject == null) {
    return null;
}
try {
    PdfFileSpec fileSpec = PdfEncryptedPayloadFileSpecFactory.wrap(fileSpecObject);
    ...
}
```

I noticed that `fileSpec.getPdfObject()` did *not* check for
`isDictionary`, that looks potentially like a problem?  Or perhaps
it's guaranteed, I wouldn't know.

One thing that's still missing from the refactored version is the
logger, that should very likely be `static final` and not be constantly
fetched (or at least that's the pattern I'm familiar with).  Also, I'm
kind of expecting that a call `logger.error(e)` or
`logger.error("Something went wrong", e)` would Do What I Mean and not
require the `getMessage()` call there.  Passing the exception will then
also allow you to see stacktraces etc., overall making that a nicer
experience.  (That's mostly in reference to SLF4J, but that's a guess at
what library's used here.)

I'm struggling with the name `getPdfStreamUf`, but I suppose that's a
technical bit that the reader more familiar with the format would
understand.

Okay so with those changes it would be a tiny bit more linear:

```
public PdfEncryptedPayloadDocument getEncryptedPayloadDocument2() {
    if (readerIsEncrypted(getReader())) {
        return null;
    }
    if (collectionIsNotViewHidden(getCatalog().getCollection())) {
        return null;
    }
    PdfDictionary fileSpecObject = getFileSpecDictionary(getEmbeddedFiles());
    if (fileSpecObject == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        PdfFileSpec fileSpec = PdfEncryptedPayloadFileSpecFactory.wrap(fileSpecObject);
        if (fileSpec == null) {
            return null;
        }
        PdfStream stream = getPdfStreamUf(getEmbeddedDictionary(fileSpec));
        if (stream == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new PdfEncryptedPayloadDocument(stream, fileSpec, getDocumentName());
    } catch (PdfException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

For me the upside is that while this is pretty heavy on the boilerplate,
each individual step is pretty clear, they also have clear names and
wherever we *don't* expect nulls, well, we just call methods and use
their return values and have the proper types anywhere (no casts
visible).  Oh yeah and I also backtracked on the small methods issue.  Actually it's pretty readable and the `return null` statements clearly delimit the steps.

Regarding the `get.get.get` chains:  It might be worth exploring whether domain specific wrapper classes would help, separate from the business logic here, by exposing the right methods, hiding most of the null checks and focusing on letting the logic here use expressive accessors.  That's somewhat simulated here by the `get(get())` invocations, e.g. `getPdfStreamUf(getEmbeddedDictionary(fileSpec))` really wants to look like `fileSpec.getEmbeddedDictionary().getPdfStreamUf()`.

Comment: Going to comment on your answer bullet point per bullet point, even though you don't have bullet points. :) First item, the extracted helpers: as suggested in the previous answer, I have _unfactored_ them, because they are nothing more than glorified wrappers with a null check. I agree that naming could improve, however, now they don't exist any more. Second item, caching getters. I checked the source code of those getters and they aren't "just" simple return fields. So caching is still a good idea. Item 3, further denesting: was also suggested in the previous answer and already implemented.

Comment: About the `try`: a `PdfException` can be thrown by `PdfEncryptedPayloadFileSpecFactory.wrap()` so that is really the smallest section of code. For the `getDocumentName()` - I need a `null` check on the `PdfCollection` first, and if I put that `null` check inside `getDocumentName()`, wouldn't that change behavior? So now I have `private String getDocumentName(PdfCollection collection) {
        return collection.getInitialDocument().toUnicodeString();
    }` Next item: casts - I'll definitely have a go at that, thanks. I will continue commenting when I have processed that.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse sure I might have missed a null check when I wrote down the suggestions, I'll go over it again, of course I didn't intend to change the behaviour there.

Comment: No you are absolutely right about the `null` check, it's already done just before, so we already know that the `PdfCollection` isn't `null`.